# 'cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer' when passing structures between Go and C

Tags: go, cgo

Let's say I'm using a C library from golang that passes around information in pointers. In reality, that library is Vulkan, but my example code here will use a simpler imaginary library:

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lmyLibrary
// #include <mylib.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    config := C.MyConfig {
        pSomeStr: C.CString("foo"),
    }

    callPrefs := C.MyCallPrefs {
        pConfig: &config,
    }

    C.MySomeCall(&callPrefs)
}
```

This would give me the error `cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer`. Other similar posts have *only* suggested downgrading to and older version of Go as a solution, which seems like an anti-solution of sorts. Is there some way to get these structures into CGO calls without such measures? In this context, the structures aren't used by either the C or Go code after the call has been completed - Go can safely free them up past that point.\

**Update:** The cleanest I have found so far is to use `C.malloc` to allocate the correct size of memory, cast it to the structure type and assign fields. This is ugly, however, and seems to be unreliable - after refactoring this behaviour into a reusable function it once again fails.

Comment: Allocating C memory in C isn't unreliable, what you're doing is unreliable and that's why Go is preventing it.

Comment: @JimB in this particular context there should be no cause for this to be unreliable. The structure is predictably only used by the library for the duration of the function call. And to clarify - by "unreliable", I meant that sometimes it would panic with the titular error, and sometimes would not, depending on slight adjustments to the code that should not make a difference.

Comment: The cgo check does its best to detect passing nested Go pointers to C functions, it does not mean it can't be subverted. You can use `cgocheck=2` for more strict checking. The Go garbage collector is concurrent, and there's no guarantee that it's won't collect that memory _during_ the call either. You can turn off `cgocheck` globally at runtime and use `runtime.KeepAlive` if you absolutely must, but relying on setting the correct `GODEBUG` variables makes your code less portable.